# how i can list of videos in youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I have the embed code of a youtube channel:

```
<object width="560" height="340" >
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/....."></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/....." type="application/x-shockwave-flash"   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" width="560" height="340"></embed>
</object>
```

It also populates but I want a complete list of videos on bottom or right side can anybody tell me how to do this?